# Parsing a multi-line fixed format text file

Tags: c#, parsing, powershell

I'm trying to parse some data in a fixed format text file where each "record" is spread over a number of lines, as so ...

```
 MAILBOX: 10013      Created: 01/20/09  4:39 pm
    MSGS: 0         UNPLAYED: 0           URGENT: 0          RECEIPT: 0
  LCOS: RBC Standard    : 20            FCOS: RBC Standard      : 20 
  GCOS: Default GCOS 1  : 1             NCOS: Default           : 1 
  TCOS: Default TCOS 1  : 1             RCOS:                   : 1 
BAD LOGS: 0         LAST LOG: NEVER                             MINS:      0.0
  PASSWD: Y            TUTOR: N              DAY: M            NIGHT: M       
    NAME:                                   CODE: 
   EXTEN: 10013                            INDEX: 0
ATTEN DN:                                  INDEX: 0         
DISTRIBUTION LISTS WITH CHANGE RIGHTS:
    all
DISTRIBUTION LISTS WITH REVIEW RIGHTS:
    all
```

I've used [File Helpers](http://www.filehelpers.com/) before for single line records, and it's been very useful. Checking it's documentation, it does have a `MultiRecordEngine` feature, but this is going to mean ...

- a class for each line ... *not a problem*
- calculating the exact size of each fixed format field ... *painful and open to error*
- logic to check each line

And a further wrinkle I found was the *fixed format* is actually *not fixed*, i.e. there are different format lines depending on the target record, so some have 21 lines, some 22, 23, 24, etc.

I have found a Java flat file parsing library, [FFP](http://jffp.sourceforge.net/), but I'm a .NET, C#, PowerShell coder

Are there better ways of handling this sort of parsing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a lexer. Your record is too big to use a single Regex to parse, so you have to write one regex for each line, and a state machine to validate that the lines follows in the right order.

Or you can use a general purpose lexer/parser to generate the code for you. Wikipedia has long [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators). The [Gold](http://www.goldparser.org/index.htm) parser looks like a good candidate.

I would not try to do the lexing/parsing in PowerShell. I would rather write the code as C# or F# and use the assembly from PowerShell.

**Edit:** I've just looked at FileHelpers library. You could create a [Multirecord Engine](http://www.filehelpers.com/example_multirecords.html) with a .NET Type that matches each line in you source record. All you have to do then is parse the result array for valid order and create objects.

Comment: Thanks for the response ... oh!, this is getting more complicated than I thought  :-(

Comment: Yeap, that was the direction I was going, but I was hoping there was a simpler solution out there.

Answer (score 3):

I've done similar in powershell, and found that using a regex in a here-string is much easier to work with:

http://mjolinor.wordpress.com/2012/01/05/powershell-multiline-regex-matching/